# Writing $ h(z) =\frac{ z + i}{z^2 +1} $ in standard form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My attempt:

$ h(z) =\frac{ z + i}{z^2  +1}$

Let $z = x + iy$

Then $$ \frac{ z + i}{z^2  +1} = \frac{x + iy + i}{x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy + 1}$$

This is approximately where I get stuck. I'm supposed to rewrite this function in the form: $ w = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

How do I go about doing that?

-- Edit

Using a hint from @DanielFischer in my comments I see that $ z^2 -1 $ can be rewritten as $ (z - i)(z+i)$ - plugging this into the expression I get:$$ h(z) = \frac{1}{z-i}$$

And moving things around I ultimately end up with $$ w = \frac{x}{x + (y-1)} - \frac{i(y-1)}{x + y - 1}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: $z^2 + 1 = (z-i)(z+i)$.

Comment: *face-palm* Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your denominators should be $x^2 + (y-1)^2$ but I think you are basically there now.